# Method [sendEmail] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, sentinel

I am new to laravel 5.3 . I am using cartalyst sentinel for authentication

**Web.php**

```
Route::post('/register','RegistrationController@register');
Route::get('/activate/{email}/{activationCode}' , 'RegistrationController@activate');
```

**RegistrationController.php**

```
public function register(Request $request){
    $user = Sentinel::register($request->all());
    $activation = Activation::create($user);
    $role = Sentinel::findRoleBySlug('student');
    $role->users()->attach($user);
    $this->sendEmail($user,$activation->code);
    Alert::info('Mail has been sent to activate your account', 'Confirmation Email')->persistent("Close this");
    return redirect::back();
}
```

**authenticate method in registration controller -**

```
public function activate($email,$activationCode){

    $user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();

    $sentinelUser = Sentinel::findById($user->id);

    if(Activation::complete($sentinelUser, $activationCode)){

        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

[image: this is the image of complete code of registrationController]

when i tried to submit the button then i got this error -

> BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 82: Method [sendEmail] does not exist.

Please help me , Thanks

Comment: Well, is there a `function sendEmail` in your RegistrationController?

Comment: yes there is sendEmail() function in register function

Comment: Can you post the complete code of your RegistrationController?

Comment: @DeepGaganGuru You're calling it in your register function, but have you actually declared it in your RegistrationController class? You need to declare your function before you can use it.

Comment: how can i declare it? @aynber

Comment: i have uploaded the pic of complete code registrationController.php @Paras

Comment: You need to create the function within your RegistrationController class. How you do that is up to you.

Comment: There is no sendEmail function in your RegistrationController. That's why this error

Comment: how can i do that ?  what can i code in that function ?

Comment: That kind of question goes beyond the scope of what we can help you with. I'd suggest finding some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->sendEmail($user,$activation->code);` is trying to call on a method that is supposed to be existing somewhere, but it's not finding it.

You can simply define the function somewhere with all the logics you want. e.g.

`private function SendEmail($user, $activation->code) {
    // your logic goes here
}`

Hope this will solve your problem....